# "In-Scene" animation vs NLA "cyclic-type" animation. Which is more commonly used?

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

Before I start I want to inform everyone that this is indeed a cross post from Reddit. I will provide the link below. No one was able to answer this question on Reddit so I thought I would try my luck here.

Let me elaborate on my question and define my terms:
Lets assume one already has the proper rig setup and is all ready to start animating. Lets say we want to make a simple fight scene with some running characters.

In-Scene: We can animate everything directly in scene on the fly. This includes keying in the run sequence and the punching sequences. This way; every run and punch will look different.

NLA/Cyclic: We can also create different actions in the action editor and use them in the NLA editor and blend them together as appropriate. For example, we can make a run cycle, punch cycle, jump cycle, etc. We can use the NLA editor to start running then a smooth blend to punch , etc.
I am curious as to what most people prefer to use here when making animated shorts vs games.

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/5hma29/inscene_animation_vs_nla_cyclictype_animation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what is used more, a more relevant gauge would be who uses what methods.

You will find that games have a set of preset animations such as walk, run jump, shoot, flip, punch etc and these animation clips are repeated constantly as the animation used is "patched together" at run time based on user input.

As for using NLA, you will find at one end is the home user starting out or animating for their own enjoyment. This user will be more inclined to use the NLA to repeat an animation and mix in small variations to add variety to the loop, with the aim of completing as much animation as possible in the shortest amount of time.

At the other extreme you have studios like Pixar or Dreamworks. To animate a feature release like How to Train Your Dragon or Finding Dory you can expect every main character in every scene to be animated by hand, background characters such as crowd simulations will make use of a collection of preset animations. It is possible that preset animation loops might get re-used in an animated TV series where more animation is expected to be completed in the same timeframe, think of Penguins of Madagascar - they have some common moves that they repeat in almost every episode.